# Which root systems admit a proper root subsystem with full span?

Tags: root-systems, coxeter-groups, semisimple-lie-algebras

Let $\Phi$ be an irreducible root system of $\mathrm{rank}(\Phi) = n$. I am allowing the case where $\Phi$ is not reduced.

Say that a subset $\Psi \subset \Phi$ is a *root subsystem* if it is a root system in its own right. For example, the intersection of $\Phi$ with any proper linear subspace of $\mathrm{span}(\Phi)$ is a root subsytem.

I would like to list all the examples of pairs $(\Phi,\Psi)$ where $\Psi$ is a full rank root subsystem of $\Phi$, namely $\mathrm{span}(\Psi) = \mathrm{span}(\Phi)$.

An obvious family of examples includes $(BC_n,B_n)$ and $(BC_n,C_n)$.
Possibly there are other examples? How  to systematically find all such pairs?

A textbook reference would also be appreciated.

Comment: Here is another example I was able to find: both $B_n$ and $C_n$ contain the sum over $n$ copies of $A_1$. In this example $\Psi$ is reducible.

Comment: $D_n$ is also inside both $B_n$ and $C_n$ (I guess I missed some obvious cases...)

Comment: $A_2$ inside $G_2$ also seems to work.

Comment: The introductory book by Onishchik and Vinberg describes an algorithm which solves this I think. It is contained in exercises 29-43 of Section 2 ,Chapter 4. It is a problem book and the solutions are not included, but I am writing up a solution to these exercises anyway and if you would like I can share them with you. Contact me in private (if there is such a thing on this website).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a strategy to find such root subsystems for irreducible (reduced) root systems:

Take the [extended Dynkin diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynkin_diagram#/media/File:Affine_Dynkin_diagrams.png) of the root system you're looking at, and remove one of the vertices (and the edges touching it). You are left with a Dynkin diagram of the same rank as the original one, and this gives a root subsystem.

This gives the following proper root subsystems of full rank:

- For type $A_n$: None
- For type $B_{n\ge 3}$: $D_i \times B_{n-i}$ (for $ 2\le i \le n$)
- For type $C_{n\ge 2}$: $C_i \times C_{n-i}$ (for $ 1\le i \le n-1$)
- For type $D_{n\ge 4}$: $D_i \times D_{n-i}$ (for $2 \le i \le n-2$)
- For type $E_6$: $A_1 \times A_5$ and $A_2 \times A_2 \times A_2$
- For type $E_7$: $A_1 \times D_6$, $A_2 \times A_5$, $A_3 \times A_3 \times A_1$, and $A_7$
- For type $E_8$: $A_1 \times E_7$, $A_2 \times E_6$, $A_3 \times D_5$, $A_4 \times A_4$, $A_5 \times A_1 \times A_2$, $A_7 \times A_1$, $D_8$ and $A_8$
- For type $F_4$: $A_1 \times C_3$, $A_2 \times A_2$, and $B_4$
- For type $G_2$: $A_1 \times A_1$ and $A_2$.

---

**Added**: In the first version of this answer, I thought this (with iteration, see below) would be enough, but it is not. For example, the inclusion $D_n \subset C_n$ does not show up yet. In a way, this procedure only "sees" subsystems which contain the highest root, which is always a long root. In the case of BCFG root systems i.e. those with two different root lengths, we also have to look at an extension of the Dynkin diagram with the (negative of the) highest *short* root, and then erase one of the other vertices. The diagrams look like this:
[image]
and we get the following possibilities which have not already been listed:

- For type $B_{n\ge 3}$: $B_i \times B_{n-i}$ (for $ 1\le i \le n$)
- For type $C_{n\ge 2}$: $D_i \times C_{n-i}$ (for $ 2\le i \le n$)
- For type $F_4$: $C_4$, $A_1 \times A_3$, and $B_3 \times A_1$

I have a feeling, but no rigorous proof yet, that this plus the following iteration procedure exhausts all possibilities.

One word about why this procedure with the Dynkin diagram first extended by the negative of the highest, or highest short, root works: Well, what we are doing with such extended Dynkin diagrams is writing down the angle and length relations between some roots. As soon as he resulting diagram is a union of standard (non-extended) Dynkin diagrams, we know by the classification that the roots making up the vertices do generate a root system of the respective type. Now in both cases, when we first extend the Dynkin diagram with the negative -of-highest(-short) root vertex, and then remove a different vertex, what remains is a classical Dynkin diagram; meaning that the roots corresponding to the remaining vertices (all but one of them from the original basis, one the negative of the highest (short) root) will generate such a classical root system. And it is obviously of full rank and contained in our original root system.

---

Now in a second step, one can iterate the procedure until one arrives at all factors being of type $A$ (note that $A_1 =B_1 =C_1$, $B_2=C_2$, $D_2 = A_1 \times A_1$ and $D_3 =A_3$). E.g. within $F_4$ we further have
$$A_1 \times C_3 \supset A_1\times A_1 \times \underbrace{C_2}_{=B_2} \supset A_1 \times A_1 \times \underbrace{A_1 \times A_1}_{C_1 \times C_1}$$
as well as
$$B_4 \supset D_4 \qquad ( \supset \underbrace{A_1 \times A_1}_{D_2} \times \underbrace{A_1 \times A_1}_{D_2})$$
and also
$$C_4 \supset C_2 \times C_2.$$

Note that the only root systems of rank $n$ which do not contain an $n$-fold product of
$A_1$ (i.e., $n$ mutually orthogonal roots) are $A_{n\ge 2}$, $D_{ n \text{ odd}}$ and $E_6$, which matches well-known results about $-id$ being in the Weyl group or not.

This somewhat matches the (far, far more elaborate) tables at the end of [R. W. Carter: *Conjugacy Classes in the Weyl Group* (Comp. Math. 25 no.1 (1972) p. 1-59)](http://www.numdam.org/article/CM_1972__25_1_1_0.pdf), although in those tables, among the "$\Gamma$"'s for the exceptional root systems, only the subsystems from my first approach are listed. I am sure there is a reason for this in that paper.

Finally, to include the non-reduced and the reducible case from here should be easy.

Comment: Dear @Torsten, I will carefully think over your answer and will then accept it. Could you please give a bit more information about why this algorithm works? Isn't Carter's paper about conjugacy classes in the Weyl group?

Comment: don't you agree $D_n \subset C_n$? After all, $D_n$ can be identified with $\pm e_i \pm e_j$ and $C_n$ can idenfied with the above together with $\pm 2e_i$.

Comment: your answer adds a lot of information and identifies additional pairs, thanks!

Comment: Carter's paper is about many things, it's just that the tables at the end, which have entirely different purposes, *also* list all (not just the full rank) root subsystems of the exceptional root systems.

Comment: Of course you're right, the short roots of $C_n$ are $D_n$, silly me! -- Now, to see why the algorithm gives full rank subsystems is not too hard, but I can add a little about that. But now the $D_n \subset C_n$ example shows that it does not exhaust all possibilities -- I will try to repair that. First idea is that in root systems with two different root lengths, the algorithm only sees those subsystems which contain the highest root, i.e. one of the long ones, that's why the $D_n \subset C_n$ does not show up. Maybe by considering the highest short root one can fix that.

Comment: So I've added that kind of approach and with that, besides $D_n \subset C_n$ (can't believe I doubted that), found several new subsystems in the cases $B$, $C$ and $F_4$: Please check those. I will add a few more words about why this procedure finds subsystems; and, I hope to find an argument why it should find *all* of them (but don't have one yet).

Comment: thanks! Thats quite impressive for a stack exchange answer!

Comment: Can we be sure that there are no root-subsystems of the one of type $A_n$? How would i prove that?

Comment: You mean that $A_n$ has no proper root subsystem of full rank? Well, what $??_n$ could that be? (Since all roots in $A_n$ are of the same length and hence types BCFG are out, I think equivalently one must show that no $A_n$ contains four roots which have the relations of a basis of $D_4$. That rules out all $D_{n\ge 4}$ as well as the $E_i$ (which all contain $D_4$).)